# Can I reset content so that when I enable notifications, no new notification emails go to existing users?

Tags: notifications

I disabled the [Notifications](https://drupal.org/project/notifications) module a couple years ago when my blog became less active and when I was editing pages to prepare for a relaunch. Now I am preparing to relaunch it and I would like to let the notifications happen again. But I am wary that Drupal is going to blast out emails to everyone for all the edits I've made. Is there a way to reset things so that I can be sure no notifications will be sent out until I post actual new content?

This is Drupal6, btw

Comment: well, I never found a solution to this. I put the site in maintenance mode, re-enabled notifications, and it promptly sent emails out with links to 63 "new" posts. Oh well.